# How can I pass a list of strings to xargs for simultaneous wget

Tags: bash, sed, xargs

I have an array (list) of strings that contain a url appended with a custom directory name

```
urls="http://domain.com/book1**Shakespeare http://domain.com/book2**King http://domain.com/book3**Twain"
```

- The url portion of each string (before **) makes a request for a .zip file which I'd
  like to pass to wget.
- The second portion of each string (after **) is the directory I'd like to put the file from the wget request into

So ultimately, what I'm expecting for a directory structure would be:

```
/Shakespeare/
    book.zip
/King/
    book.zip
/Twain/
    book.zip
```

What I've got so far is...

```
echo $urls | xargs -n 1 -P 8 | sed 's/\*\*.*//'
```

This correctly outputs the 5 url's that I will need to wget, without the **author appended to the end of each. (i.e. `http://domain.com/book2**King` becomes `http://domain.com/book2`)

Now...I'd like to pass these new *properly formatted* download urls to wget, while also somehow passing the stripped off `**author` portion to supply as part of the wget *destination* option

The main reason I'm using "xargs" is because I've been able to pass a list of urls to it to and wget them ***simultaneously***. I'm hoping that I can download them simultaneously to different destination directories, in the same call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $urls | sed 's/\*\*/ -P /g' | xargs -n 3 -P 8 wget
```

This should do what you want, though a better way might be to move the logic upstream, i.e. wherever you are generating `$urls`. Also, I'm not clear on whether you needed to add `.zip`. If so, you can do that within the `sed` pattern as well.

**Explanation:**

`wget` can use the `-P` option to specify a prefix/download location.

So if your objective is to run each command as something that looks like this:

```
wget http://domain.com/book1 -P Shakespeare
```

Then I would first use `sed` to replace each `**` with `-P`, then pipe into `xargs`, using `-n 3` because by the time it gets to `xargs`, you want to pass three words at a time to `wget`.

Comment: Boom, this is just what I asked for and works perfectly. (Didn't need to append ".zip" as it's handled via the url redirect.) Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is pretty awkward using shell pipes. The main problem is that you're trying to get the standard output of one process (`echo` and/or `sed`) to be used as *parameters* to another (`wget`). Pipes aren't going to help you here, since by design these connect `stdin` of one process to `stdout` of another. This conflates the stuff that's processed by the tool with the parameters describing *how* that processing happens. So pipes aren't really what you want.

You might be able to hack it with `sed` or `awk` plus tools like `split`, `paste`, etc., but you'll at least want to write a full-on shell script, rather than just a pipeline. But I'd really recommend using a more full-featured scripting language, particularly with better string processing. The other thing you'd want is to be able to launch subprocesses.

This all points to something like Python as a good choice. Here is an example implementation (tested, but not rigorously), that should do what you want.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import urllib.request # Check out the `requests` 3rd-party library too, it's great

# Split string into (URL, author) tuples. You can read this from stdin or a file, too.
urls = 'http://domain.com/book1**Shakespeare http://domain.com/book2**King' # etc
args = map(lambda x: x.split('**'), urls.split(' '))

def download_file(url, author_name):
    if not os.path.isdir(author_name):
        os.mkdir(author_name)
    # Transfer URLs contents to local file
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u, open(author_name + '/book.zip', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(u.read())

# Run the download function in a pool of worker processes (defaults to CPU count)
# A simple `os.system()` or `os.popen()` call would work too
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(download_file, args)
```

Comment: Actually, this kind of usage is what `xargs` is for.

Comment: I've never really used Bash before, so I imagine my approach is mighty awkward given the amount of time it's taken me to figure out! :P  What got me started is a little Automator workflow I built that _sort of_ handles this. It involved a few "shell script" pieces to do some renaming, moving, etc...I figured maybe i could port the whole thing to a Bash script to improve upon it.

I've never really worked with Python much either though so appreciate the nudge in that direction, will give it a shot!